# Using Visual Studio for Python Files

Tags: python, visual-studio, solution

I have multiple python files for a school project that I want to open and edit in visual studio but to make it simple I want to have them all be a solution or project in visual studio, the code provided to me though was from my professor and he just used emacs to create all the files. Is there a way I can have the directory of .py files opened all together as a sln? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't tried this myself yet, but did you look into [Python Tools for Visual Studio](http://pytools.codeplex.com/)? 
You didn't specify which version of Visual Studio you are using. pytools is for VS 2010.